# Hardware and internet requirements for 1080/30p streaming, if video source is external

Tags: streaming, broadcasting, broadcast

I have a Panasonic X1 camera that can be connected to a pc using an acquisition card. In that case its video stream could be broadcasted using OBS or similar programs.

What I miss are the requirements of the pc hardware and of the internet line. If I understood well the first should be pretty low considering that all the videomaking would be demanded to the camera and to the acquisition card, and OBS would only have to throw it online. Yet, I don't even know which parte of the PC would be needed for such a job. The CPU? The video card? The RAM?

Concerning the line, I really have no clue. Streaming 1080/30p sounds heavy but there are cell phones able to do that with a 3G connection. Would a tethering connection to a 3G/4G phone be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Connection Speed**

For H.264 1080p30 streaming with typical compression (6 Mbps), I would recommend an Internet upload speed of around 10 Mbps minimum.

**Hardware**

OBS Studio suggests the following system requirements:

- AMD FX series or Intel i5 2000-series processor (dual or 4-core
  preferable) or higher.
- At least 4 GB of RAM (recommended, but not necessary).

For Windows:

- DirectX 10.1 compatible GPU.
- Windows 7 SP1 or newer.

For macOS:

- Intel CPU (PPC is not supported).
- OpenGL 3.2 compatible GPU.
- macOS 10.11 or newer.

As for mobile streaming, 4G LTE (between 2-5 Mbps) can manage 1080p30 - albeit with high compression.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for my late one.
I have to admit that these don't look like terribly high requirements, I thought it could be worse.